# user menu not changing

Tags: 7

I think that was drupal 6 where the user menu e.g.:

-Login

will turn into:

-Log out

link when the user is not logged in and when the user is logged in respectively.

I do not know how to make this behave like this in Drupal 7.

Any ideas?